# Java, trying to compare userinput to a textfile algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, text, user-input

I am trying to compare this code to a text file to get the output:

"This is english". I have a couple of textfiles that has english and other languages text in it, but how do I compare my input code (Scanner input) to the textfile to see if its english or not? I have this code "LangLabel curLabel = LangLabel.EN;" that basicly specifices that its english but I would like it to check all the files and then compare and see which one it is.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type in a language");
        String thetext = scan.nextLine();

        Main lf = new Main();
        String sentence = thetext;
        sentence = sentence.replace(".", "");
        List<LetterCount> letterCounts = lf.calculateLetterCounts(sentence);

        for (LetterCount letterCount : letterCounts) {
            System.out.print(letterCount.getLetter() + " ");
            System.out.print(letterCount.getCount() + "/");
            System.out.print(sentence.length() + " - ");
            double percentage = 100.0 * letterCount.getCount() / sentence.length();
            System.out.println(String.format("%,.2f", percentage) + "%");
        }
        String text = "Grace Hopper (född Murray), född den 9 december 1906 i New York, död den 1 januari 1992 i Arlington, Virginia, var en amerikansk dator-pionjär och sjöofficer (flottiljamiral).";


        text = text.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\s]", "");

        text = text.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

        String[] words = text.split(" ");

        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.print("'" + word + "' ");
        }

        HashMap<LangLabel, Language> languages = new HashMap<>();



        System.out.println("\n ---- Loop enum:");
        for (LangLabel label : LangLabel.values()) {

            String content = Utils.readTextFile("assets/lang-samples/" + label + ".txt");

            languages.put(label, new Language(content, label));
            LangLabel curLabel = LangLabel.EN;
            System.out.println(curLabel.getName());
        }

        //System.out.println(content);
    }


    public List<LetterCount> calculateLetterCounts(String sentence) {
        List<LetterCount> letterCounts = new ArrayList<>();
        char[] letters = sentence.toCharArray();
        for (char c : letters) {
            if (c != ' ') {
                addCount(letterCounts, c);
            }
        }

        return letterCounts;
    }

    private void addCount(List<LetterCount> letterCounts, char c) {
        for (LetterCount letterCount : letterCounts) {
            if (letterCount.getLetter() == c) {
                letterCount.incrementCount();
                return;
            }
        }
```